# What causes this "Missing argument 2 for Categories::posts()" error?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on a small blogging application. There is a clear separation between its back-end and its front-end.

The back-end is an **API**, made with Codeigniter 3, that spits out pages, posts, pagination etc.

In this API, there is an `_initPagination()`, within the **Posts** controller, that is used throughout the site:

```
private function _initPagination($path, $totalRows, $query_string_segment = 'page') {
//load and configure pagination 
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $path;
    $config['query_string_segment'] = $query_string_segment; 
    $config['enable_query_strings'] =TRUE;
    $config['reuse_query_string'] =TRUE;
    $config['total_rows'] = $totalRows;
    $config['per_page'] = 12;
    if (!isset($_GET[$config['query_string_segment']]) || $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] < 1) {
        $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] = 1;
    }
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $limit = $config['per_page'];
    $offset = ($this->input->get($config['query_string_segment']) - 1) * $limit;

    return ['limit' => $limit, 'offset' => $offset];
}
```

The **Categories** controller displays, among others, *post by category*:

```
public function posts($path, $category_id) {
    //load and configure pagination 
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $path;
    $config['base_url'] = base_url('/categories/posts/' . $category_id);
    $config['query_string_segment'] = 'page';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows_by_category($category_id);
    $config['per_page'] = 12;

    if (!isset($_GET[$config['query_string_segment']]) || $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] < 1) {
        $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] = 1;
    }

    $limit = $config['per_page'];
    $offset = ($this->input->get($config['query_string_segment']) - 1) * $limit;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
    $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();
    $data['category_name'] = $this->Categories_model->get_category($category_id)->name;
    $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts_by_category($category_id, $limit, $offset);

    // All posts in a CATEGORY
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}
```

The code above has a bug who's cause I can not find. The error message the application throws is:

```
Missing argument 2 for Categories::posts()
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Does the error shows any line number ?

Comment: It shows line number 11, which is this: `public function posts($path, $category_id)`

Comment: where did you called this function

Comment: @RazvanZamfir, it means that you've passed 1 argument instead of 2 to this method.

Comment: The flaw is not in the function `posts()`. It is happening where you call `post()`. You are not supplying the `$category_id` argument.

Comment: @DFriend If I comment out this line `$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $path;` and pass *only* `$category_id` as an argument - posts($category_id), there is no error.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir, then you can do this `public function posts($path = null, $category_id)`.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir, I cannot tell you why that works because you have not yet shown how and where you make the call to `Categories::posts`.  BTW, it is a spectacularly bad idea to be dynamically changing the value of `$config['base_url'] `. That item is used in many ways by the framework and is expected to represent the main entry point to a domain. You're probably going to introduce hard to debug behavior by messing with that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you've passed 1 argument instead of 2 to this method. Send in it `$path` and `$category_id`

**or**

if you wanna say that sometimes the second argument could be absent, then rewrite it like:

`public function posts($path, $category_id = null) {`

In this case `$category_id` will be `null` by default.

or

`public function posts($path = null, $category_id) {`

In this case `$path`  will be `null` by default.

Comment: Now I get the error `Trying to get property of non-object` on this line: `$data['category_name'] = $this->Categories_model->get_category($category_id)->name;`.

Comment: That because `$this->Categories_model->get_category($category_id)` **returns not an object**. And you cannot use `->name` syntax with it. Check this method(method name is `get_category`, model name is `Categories_model`). Also this is a new question and it would be better to look up on it with the code of this method in a new topic. I've answered you on your actual question.

Comment: Your actual question is solved? You can ask your next question with required information for solving it in a separate post.

Comment: It's not answered because the non-object error is caused by `$category_id` being `null`. `$category_id` must have a non-null value or `$this->Categories_model->get_category($category_id)` fails and returns false (instead of an object).

Comment: Yes, cause I told you **or**, one more time read please my answer. `$category = null` means that sometimes `$category` could be absent. So, if it should be here always -> you don't need `= null`. So, you must send to this method **posts** 2 parameters, **$path** and **$category**. And you've passed the only **1**. Check where you're using this method and check your variables, it should looks like **posts($pth,$cat_id)** or similar.